# position text of radio-button on its left side

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button

I have a radio-button looking like this

[image: radio-button]

created by this script:

```py
import tkinter as tk

app = tk.Tk()
rbtn = tk.Radiobutton(text="A Radiobutton")
rbtn.pack()
app.mainloop()
```

I would like the text `A Radiobutton` to be on the left side. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

you could use  `.place(x=,y=)`

```py
import tkinter as tk

app = tk.Tk()
rbtn = tk.Radiobutton()#text="A Radiobutton")
rbtn.place( x=175 )
label=tk.Label(text="A Radiobutton")
label.place(x=100)
app.mainloop()
```

[image: resulting window]

Comment: That would look like I want it to - unless I hover over or click the radio-button.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a label and a radiobutton without text in a frame, with the label on the left and the radiobutton on the right. This is exactly the sort of think that Frame widgets were designed for.

```
import tkinter as tk

app = tk.Tk()

frame = tk.Frame(app)
frame.pack()

lbl = tk.Label(frame, text="A Radiobutton")
rbtn = tk.Radiobutton(frame, text="")

rbtn.pack(side="right")
lbl.pack(side="left", fill="x")

app.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot of tk radiobutton]

Another solution is to switch to the ttk Radiobutton, because it allows you to change the layout of the widget.

I'm not a ttk expert, but this seems to work for me on my machintosh. It's likely not exactly what you want, but you can read more about styles and themes on [tkdocs.com](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/styles.html).

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

app = tk.Tk()
style = ttk.Style()
style.layout('custom.TRadiobutton',
         [('Radiobutton.padding',
           {'children':
            [('Radiobutton.button', {'side': 'right', 'sticky': ''}), # Just need to change indicator's 'side' value
             ('Radiobutton.focus', {'side': 'left',
                                    'children':
                                    [('Radiobutton.label', {'sticky': 'nswe'})],
                                    'sticky': ''})],
            'sticky': 'nswe'})])

var = tk.IntVar(value=1)
rbtn1 = ttk.Radiobutton(app, style="custom.TRadiobutton", text="A Radiobutton", value=0, variable=var)
rbtn2 = ttk.Radiobutton(app, style="custom.TRadiobutton", text="Another Radiobutton", value=1, variable=var)

rbtn1.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
rbtn2.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

app.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot of ttk radiobutton]

Comment: That would look like I want it to - unless I hover over or click the radio-button.

Comment: @LukasFun Why, what happens when you hover or click.

Comment: If the text is part of the radio-button as with the example in the question, hovering over that text highlights the entire radio-button and clicking on it is recognized as the appropriate event. While it is certainly possible to code the label to act in the same way, I expect it to be excruciatingly complicated.

Comment: @LukasFun: I've updated my answer to show how it's possible to change the layout of a ttk radiobutton.

Comment: That second example doesn't produce the circles showing which one of the buttons is selected. Is this the exact code you used? If so, then maybe this is an OS specific thing since I am on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: @LukasFun: Yes, this is the exact code I used, and yes, you may have to tweak it for different platforms. The point of the answer was to show that ttk gives you a bit more control over the look of the widget. You can get the layout used on your platform by doing something like `print(style.layout('custom.TRadiobutton'))` after creating the `style` variable.

Comment: @LukasFun Try changing `'Radiobutton.button'` to `'Radiobutton.indicator'`.

Comment: That seems to work, but now the indicator is a diamond shape.